# Why won't my MacBook Pro boot from a Linux Live CD?

Tags: unix, dual-boot

Whenever I try to boot up from a live cd, it starts to boot and then it tells me:

> **No bootable file system available.**

It's an **Early 2011 MacBook Pro 13" 8,1** with the 2.3 GHz Core i5.

What's going on?

Answer (score 4):

Macs use the **EFI Firmware** (BIOS for Windows).

You need to download a special Mac ISO that allows to boot on both BIOS and EFI Systems.

- For Ubuntu 11.10 you can download the specific Mac image here:
  [**64-bit Mac (AMD64) desktop CD**](http://cdimage.ubuntu.com/releases/11.10/release/)
- By experience I know that the following distros allow to boot on EFI systems using the "standard" ISO: Debian, Fedora, Linux Mint

Your questions is related to [this here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/37999/what-is-different-about-the-mac-iso-image) on askubuntu.

Comment: That's interesting because I was trying to boot the latest Fedora release. If I were to want to build arch on a new partition using that computer would it also cause me problems with EFI?

Answer (score 1):

You'll probably want to take a look at **[rEFIt](http://refit.sourceforge.net/)**

That's how I booted and installed Linux on my Mac. It's a very nice piece of software.

Comment: rEFIt will not make the iso bootable. It's only a 'butler' to make multi-booting more convenient. It will *not* help him, if the CD already doesn't boot even though he is holding **⌥**. However, one should use rEFIt to **sync partition tables** after a linux installation.

Comment: rEFIt isn't maintained anymore. [rEFInd](http://www.rodsbooks.com/refind/) is a fork that is still actively maintained (as of Nov 2013)

Answer (score 1):

I installed the rEFIt on my late 2011 Macbook Pro and it messed up the whole startup and login. I never got refit screen after startup which should appear after a few restarts. The opposite, after a few restarts I was not able to login in on the startup screen. The password was still workin, so I could login into the computer using ssh on another computer. Weird. I finally solved it with TimeMachine. 
Stay away from fEFIt if you're having the latest Macbook Pro with Lion.

Answer (score 1):

What other commenters have not made plain is that virtually all Linux live boot CDs presume that you'll be using them on a computer that uses BIOS (that's basically all PCs designed for Windows). [BIOS (Basic Input-Output System)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/BIOS) is computer software in the firmware of the motherboard itself that is the first thing to run at bootup of a PC.

Macs do not use BIOS at all. They use a completely different method of booting the computer, called [EFI (Extensible Firmware Interface)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extensible_Firmware_Interface).

So you need to see if your preferred distribution of Linux has a live boot CD that will work with EFI and not BIOS.